# Pass extra data with zxing scanning intent

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm integrating a barcode scanner using https://github.com/zxing. I would like to pass some additional data - `uuid` below - along with the barcode.

Both `uuid1` and `uuid2` below yields `null`. WHat am I missing?

```
public void startScanner(String uuid){
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);

    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);

    Intent intent = integrator.createScanIntent();
    intent.putExtra("uuid", uuid);

    startActivityForResult(intent, IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
{
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanResult != null) {
        String code = scanResult.getContents();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            String uuid1 = intent.getStringExtra("uuid");
            String uuid2 = intent.getExtras().getString("uuid");

            json.put("uuid", uuid1);
            json.put("barCode", code);
            this.webViewManager.runScript("startScannerCallback", json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same question on my end... have you found a solution? A member variable for the activity would be a workaround but I really don't like it.

Comment: @lupz No other solution that the one you mention I'm afraid. Please let me know if you figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll stick with the member variable :( ... hm ... it shouldn't be to hard to add/implement a pass-through extra-key to xzing...

Answer (score 1):

Someone on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ygg7ta/who_called_activityresultlauncherlaunch/?sort=new) told me to create a custom contract. That did the trick (but is not thread safe!):

```java
public class ScanContract extends com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ScanContract {

    private String scope;

    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    @Override
    public ScanIntentResult parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        ScanIntentResult scanIntentResult = super.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
        scanIntentResult.getOriginalIntent().putExtra("foo", scope);
        scope = null;
        return scanIntentResult;
    }
}
```

the launch call:

```java
((ScanContract)barcodeLauncher.getContract()).setScope("bar");
```

receiving the scope:

```java
String foo = result.getOriginalIntent().getStringExtra("foo");
```

Of course, this only(!) works if you don't launch the activity multiple times at the same time, as the Contract object is only instanciated once!

Oh, and also I am using the new API for getting activity results :)