# Android: pass data from initial activity (launching Zxing scanner) to onActivityResult callback

Tags: java, android, android-intent, zxing, onactivityresult

I use the library zxing-android-embedded in my Android App. Before calling initiateScan() method to start the scanner from my activity, I set a class variable scanedItemId to know on which item I clicked to scan:

```
[...]
scanedItemId = currentItem.id // The current item where we clicked on.
IntentIntegrator qrCodeScanner = new IntentIntegrator(MyActivity.this);
qrCodeScanner.setOrientationLocked(false);
qrCodeScanner.initiateScan();
[...]
```

Then I get the result via onActivityResult method. It works well but my class variable scanedItemId is null because the activity is relaunched. Is it possible to keep my initial instance of MyActivity (with the scanedItemId well set) or to pass the value I need thru the IntentIntegrator to get it back on the new instance of MyActivity?

```
[...]
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
            // Here the scanedItemId is always null.
[...]
```

If possible I wouldn't like to use a hard persistence (like db or file) to get my scanedItemId value.

Hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more custom data like this :

```
scanedItemId = currentItem.id // The current item where we clicked on.
IntentIntegrator qrCodeScanner = new IntentIntegrator(MyActivity.this);
quCodeScanner.addExtra("ITEM_ID", scanedItemId);//add your data
qrCodeScanner.setOrientationLocked(false);
qrCodeScanner.initiateScan();
```

Because library which you used didn't return your data. You can fork that library and add some code like below:

In CaptureManager class
edit initializeFromIntent method

```
if (intent != null) {
    data = intent.getIntExtra("ITEM_ID", 0);//save your data
}
```

and resultIntent method

```
intent.putExtra("ITEM_ID", data);//return your data
```

Now in onActivityResult you can get your data

```
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(resultCode, data);
if (result.getOriginalIntent().hasExtra("ITEM_ID")) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Item Id : " + String.valueOf(result.getOriginalIntent().getIntExtra("ITEM_ID",0)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: OK thanks but I can't get the extra result from the onActivityResult method. I have the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309732/pass-extra-data-with-zxing-scanning-intent

Comment: OK, so it confirms that using the library as it is, it's impossible to pass data thru its Intent. Obviously I prefer to not fork the library (mainly for maintenance reason).So either I try to use a class variable (which doesn't work for the moment because my activity is killed and re-instanciated), or I will have to find another library. Anyway, thanks for the explanation and the time you spent.